# How to override Ember.View such that all templates are searched for under a namespace

Tags: ember.js

I'm using ember-rails to take care of handlebars compilation and the rails app will have multiple Ember applications (depending on which page the user is on). To better handle file management I'd like to organize the templates under a different folder per app. However, I don't want to have to create a separate view for each template just to specify the templateName. Is there a good way to Override Ember.View for each application such that it will always look for templates under a particular namespace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can override the template resolver to accomplish this. The basic idea is to make sure that the build system like ember-rails compiles templates in the form,

```
Ember.TEMPLATES['namespace/foo/bar'] = ...
```

Then you can override the template resolver to prefix that namespace onto the template name.

```
App = Ember.Application.create({
  templateNamespace: 'initech',

  resolver: Ember.DefaultResolver.extend({
    resolveTemplate: function(parsedName) {
      parsedName.fullNameWithoutType = App.templateNamespace + '/' + parsedName.fullNameWithoutType;
      parsedName.name = App.templateNamespace + '/' + parsedName.name;

      return this._super(parsedName);
    }
  })

});
```

Here's a [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/ufapum/1/edit) example. The templates are embedded in the example but would come from the `initech` directory in your case.